# Strange chars in JSON (obtained after cURL auth)

Tags: php, arrays, curl, json

This is the function I use to grab a JSON file from [Feedbin API](https://api.feedbin.me/v2/entries.json).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://api.feedbin.me/v2/entries.json';

$username = 'my_username';  // authentication
$password = ' my_password';  // authentication

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password   // authentication
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string

print_r ($result);
?>
```

Problem is the JSON I get is a bit.. strange.
It has a lot of chars like *\u003E\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/p\u003E\n\u003Cp\u003E* ...
You can see the JSON **[here](http://ffio.it/feedbin.txt)**.

Comment: Those are unicode encoded characters .. there shouldn't be a problem.  Is there?

Comment: Oh.. I just saw them and feared there was a problem.
Are they ok or is it better to convert them?

Comment: When decoding the input with json_decode ? Or does it do that "automatically"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `json_decode` in PHP on strings that contain these encodings they will be correctly decoded.  http://json.org/ lists `\ufour-hex-digits` as a valid character.  There is no issue.

```
$ echo json_decode('"\u003E\u003C/a\u003E\u003C/p\u003E\n\u003Cp\u003E"');
></a></p>
<p>
```

Comment: Thanks! :)
Just a little OT while waiting 2 min to be able to accept the answer: since there's no index in this JSON, how should I format the foreach? Something like `foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value)` ?

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno the result of `json_decode` will be an array, so just `foreach (json_decode($result) as $obj)`

Answer (score 2):

They are valid unicode sequence. Here is a simple example

```
$data = array(
        "abc" => 'åbcdéfg'
);

// Encode
$data = json_encode($data) . "\n";

// Output Value
echo $data;

// Output Decoded Value
print_r(json_decode($data));
```

Output

```
{"abc":"\u00e5bcd\u00e9fg"}
stdClass Object
(
    [abc] => åbcdéfg
)
```